# OS X app tableview datasource updating but not reloading in tableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a Mac OS X app which populates a `tableView` with data from an external web service. If I log into my app, I can add new records, delete them, etc, and my call to `[tableView reloadData]` works exactly as I would anticipate.

Here's what puzzles me. If I log into my app (simultaneous login from two different instances - one running as an app on my machine, and one running in debug mode from Xcode) I can see the data I expected. However, if I create a new record in one instance of the app it does not load when `[tableView reloadData]` is called. The strange thing is, if I look at the data coming back from the web server it does contain the new or updated records. They just do not display.

If I log out of the other instance of the app and sign back in, boom - I see the new record. Again, if I add a record somewhere it appears in the data stream (which I have a method `[self getData]`) but when the `[tableView reloadData]` is called it still does not display the entry.

What would cause the `tableView` to not display the new data - despite its source `NSMutableArray` being updated appropriately? I've confirmed that the app is seeing the appropriate data:

```
2011-12-04 16:12:40.086 Workshop Manager[8591:707] Loading tickets from API
2011-12-04 16:12:40.711 Workshop Manager[8591:707] Load return_data into tickets and filtered_tickets
2011-12-04 16:12:40.711 Workshop Manager[8591:707] App currently has 8 tickets loaded
2011-12-04 16:13:20.437 Workshop Manager[8591:707] Refresh button pushed
2011-12-04 16:13:20.438 Workshop Manager[8591:707] Removing all existing tickets
2011-12-04 16:13:20.438 Workshop Manager[8591:707] Loading tickets from API
2011-12-04 16:13:20.774 Workshop Manager[8591:707] Load return_data into tickets and filtered_tickets
2011-12-04 16:13:20.774 Workshop Manager[8591:707] App currently has 9 tickets loaded
```

Since the app is clearly loading the new dataset, what else am I missing? Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please include some code - where are these log messages coming from, what do you do with the array that come back from your service, how do you connect to the service and so on.